# How to not trigger the hover state when mouse is at the corner of a round QPushButton？

Tags: css, qt, hover, border, qtstylesheets

I have a QPushButton with round corners:

[image]

Now, I want to changed the button's style when mouse is moving at it:

[image]

I used setStyleSheet of QPushButton:

```
QPushButton{
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    border-radius:40px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
QPushButton:hover{
    background: red;    
}
```

But not four corners:

[image]

as the 3rd image shown, the cursor is pointing at the button's right-bottom corner but aslo triggered the button's hover state. Is there a simple way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: This is a normal behaviour. in my opinion there is no simple way to do this. There could be a complex jQuery way by using a pseudo element and all. But then again I think its quite normal.

Comment: Do you also want to prevent a _click_ when the cursor is outside the outline?

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe*, there exists a more straightforward solution of that, but I just tried and it occured that implementing all the hover behaviour by hand seems the only really working way.

Generally, it's all about checking that the mouse coordinates belong to an ellipse (you can try other geometric considerations).

**Something that doesn't work:**

```
ui->myButton->installEventFilter(this);

//----------------------------------------

bool SomeWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::HoverEnter || event->type() == QEvent::HoverMove)
    {
        QHoverEvent* hoverEvent = static_cast<QHoverEvent *>(event);
        QWidget* target = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(obj);
        qreal a = target->width() / 2;
        qreal b = target->height() / 2;
        qreal x = hoverEvent->posF().x() - a;
        qreal y = hoverEvent->posF().y() - b;

        double val = (x / a) * (x / a) + (y / b) * (y / b);
        bool isInside = val <= 1;
        if (!isInside)
            return true;
        else
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
    } 
        return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

With SomeWidget, comtaining a button and event filter installed, this looked promising but works awfully =(

**Something that works as a Proof-of-Concept:**

```
CustomButton::CustomButton(QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton(parent)
{
    setProperty("my_hover", "not_hovered");
}

void CustomButton::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qreal a = width() / 2;
    qreal b = height() / 2;
    qreal x = event->pos().x() - a;
    qreal y = event->pos().y() - b;

    double val = (x / a) * (x / a) + (y / b) * (y / b);
    bool isInside = val <= 1;
    setProperty("my_hover", isInside ? "hovered" : "not_hovered" );
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
}
```

Subclassing a QPushButton worked better (code above is made a readble sample, you can improve it, of course). When implemented, it provides the button class with a custom property, which could be used like that:

```
QPushButton[my_hover="hovered"]
{
  background: red;    
}
```

To make it a perfect solution you'll probably have to care about `mouseLeaveEvent` too, thus getting rid of occasional glitches. Also, the property could probably be made boolean if it works with your Qt.

AFAIK, that's the only sure way to implement the desired behaviour you've descrived.